# Is the Update Manager release upgrade path generally fire-and-forget?

Tags: installation, 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

I am thinking of upgrading to the new 12.04 Ubuntu release.

On my last upgrade I did it from CD but I got into a bit of a tangle (although I did fix it in the end), so this time I'm planning on doing it online via the Update Manager instead.

However, my question is this: is doing an upgrade via Update Manager generally a "fire-and-forget" process?  In other words, can I set it going before going to bed, and then have it (mostly) done by the morning?

Or is it a process that periodically asks for user input and therefore requires an amount of baby-sitting?

Many thanks in advance,

thoughton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not simply like that. There are a few instances in which you have to approve certain actions. You can leave it downloading during the night, but the process of installation itself takes action from the user.